# How to render HTML string as real HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Here's what I tried and how it goes wrong.

This works:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<h1>Hi there!</h1>" }} />
```

This doesn't:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.match.description }} />
```

---

The description property is just a normal string of HTML content. However it's rendered as a string, not as HTML for some reason.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Check if the text you're trying to append to the node is not escaped like this:

```
var prop = {
    match: {
        description: '&lt;h1&gt;Hi there!&lt;/h1&gt;'
    }
};
```

Instead of this:

```
var prop = {
    match: {
        description: '<h1>Hi there!</h1>'
    }
};
```

if is escaped you should convert it from your server-side.

[image: The node is text because is escaped]

The node is text because is escaped

[image: The node is a dom node because isn't escaped]

The node is a dom node because isn't escaped

Comment: This was the issue. The description string was escaped HTML. I unescaped it and now it works fine.

Comment: Please avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` instead use `Fragment` from react v16. Check the [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49777535/7797203) by @brad-adams

Comment: Appreciate the mention @KunalParekh, but they're different things. My answer is only valid if the html is located within your app (meaning it's actually JSX). To parse HTML from an external source to jsx you'd need to seek another solution.

Comment: Convert it how? With which API or package? The answer gets you halfway there.

Comment: @TsarBomba there are lots of ways to do it: https://npm.im/html-entities

Answer (score 278):

Is `this.props.match.description` a string or an object? If it's a string, it should be converted to HTML just fine. Example:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      description: '<h1 style="color:red;">something</h1>'
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.description }} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Result: http://codepen.io/ilanus/pen/QKgoLA?editors=1011

However if description is `<h1 style="color:red;">something</h1>` without the quotes `''`, you're going to get:

```
​Object {
$$typeof: [object Symbol] {},
  _owner: null,
  key: null,
  props: Object {
    children: "something",
    style: "color:red;"
  },
  ref: null,
  type: "h1"
}
```

If It's a string and you don't see any HTML markup the only problem I see is wrong markup..

**UPDATE**

If you are dealing with HTML Entities, You need to decode them before sending them to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` that's why it's called "dangerously" :)

Working example:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      description: '&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Our Opportunity:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;'
    }
  }

   htmlDecode(input){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.htmlDecode(this.state.description) }} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `this.props.match.description` is a string, not an object. What do you mean with wrong markup? Do you mean unclosed tags? React should just render it no?

Comment: Could you paste here console.log(this.props.match.description);

Comment: One example: `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Our Opportunity:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Comment: In this case you need either to use .innerHTML or decode HTMLEntities.

Comment: Return multiple lines or HTML code with tags:
function htmlDecode(input){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;

    var returnString = '';
    for (index = 0; index < e.childNodes.length; index++) {
        // case of just a string
        if(e.childNodes[index].nodeValue){
            returnString += e.childNodes[index].nodeValue;
        }
        // case of HTML
        if(e.childNodes[index].outerHTML){
            returnString += e.childNodes[index].outerHTML;
        }
    }

    return returnString;
}

Comment: Regarding the name, it does not have to do with HTML entities, rather with XSS attacks. See https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml. It's dangerous if the HTML you're setting is user-supplied.

Answer (score 152):

I use 'react-html-parser'

```
yarn add react-html-parser
```

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'; 

<div> { ReactHtmlParser (html_string) } </div>
```

Source [on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Lifting up @okram's comment for more visibility:

> from its github description: Converts HTML strings directly into React
> components avoiding the need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML from
> npmjs.com A utility for converting HTML strings into React components.
> Avoids the use of dangerouslySetInnerHTML and converts standard HTML
> elements, attributes and inline styles into their React equivalents.

Comment: Does this library use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" in the background?

Comment: from its github description:
```Converts HTML strings directly into React components avoiding the need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML```
from npmjs.com
```A utility for converting HTML strings into React components. Avoids the use of dangerouslySetInnerHTML and converts standard HTML elements, attributes and inline styles into their React equivalents.```

Comment: For React 17.0+, I use a similar library called "html-react-parser", which is currently supported. https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser

Comment: From FAQ section of html-react-parser: "this library is not XSS (cross-site scripting) safe." https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser

Comment: You may need to install with : npm install react-html-parser

Answer (score 68):

If you have HTML in a string I would recommend using a package called [`html-react-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser).

### Installation

NPM:

```
npm install html-react-parser
```

yarn:

```
yarn add html-react-parser
```

### Usage

```js
import parse from 'html-react-parser'
const yourHtmlString = '<h1>Hello</h1>'
```

code:

```html
<div>
    {parse(yourHtmlString)}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with Next.JS as well

Comment: Can confirm it works great!

Comment: heads up that this package is a security risk because it doesn't sanitize the html. only use it with a package like sanitize-html: https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html

Answer (score 27):

I use innerHTML together a ref to span:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Sample() {
  const spanRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);
  const [someHTML,] = useState("some <b>bold</b>");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (spanRef.current) {
      spanRef.current.innerHTML = someHTML;
    }
  }, [spanRef.current, someHTML]);

  return <div>
    my custom text follows<br />
    <span ref={spanRef} />
  </div>
}
```

note on XSS attack: to prevent malicious injected script to be executed the html code need to be **sanitized**. See follow example:

```
/**
 * example how to retrieve a reference to an html object
 */

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as DOMPurify from 'dompurify'; // add with yarn add DOMPurify and @types/DOMPurify

/**
 * this component can be used into another for example <Sample/>
 */
export default function Sample() {
    /**
     * 1) spanRef is now a React.RefObject<HTMLSpanElement>
     * initially created with null value
     */
    const spanRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);

    /**
     * 2) later, when spanRef changes because html span element with ref attribute,
     * follow useEffect hook will triggered because of dependent [spanRef].
     * in an if ( spanRef.current ) that states if spanRef assigned to valid html obj
     * we do what we need : in this case through current.innerHTML
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        if (spanRef.current) {
            // follow malicious code injects
            // spanRef.current.innerHTML = "sample xss<img src onerror=\"alert('code exec')\"/>";

            // follow malicious code will sanitized to <img src>
            spanRef.current.innerHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize("sample xss prevented<img src onerror=\"alert('code exec')\"/>")
        }
    }, [spanRef]);

    return <div>
        my custom text follows<br />
        {/* ref={spanRef] will update the React.RefObject `spanRef` when html obj ready */}
        <span ref={spanRef} />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I like this, no need for additional libraries or reliance on server-side when you don't have that luxury.  Inspired by you, but in a class component I did 
```componentDidMount() {
    this.message.current.innerHTML = this.state.selectedMessage.body;
  }```
body is the escaped html for me.

Comment: A little explanation to the answer could have done wonders.

Comment: @letsbondiway see UPDATE part on my answer.

Comment: @LorenzoDelana Thank you for the detailed updated answer. Now it is really helpful. However, I had a question - do you think there is any kind of security risks associated with this solution? I mean attacks like XSS, HTML injection and all. My understanding is it is safe from these as we are not using dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: @letsbondiway with or without setting an html element property in a direct way such the innerHTML can be dangerous if security criteria aren't applied ; from my point of view, but of course I could miss something, there isn't specific issues if you know what you are doing and how these could negatively used from an attackers. For counter example you can regularly use standard input box provided by the framework that of course is good because best-practices are already taken in account, but if you use that text as a part of raw sql query an attacker could inject a tautology to extract all data.

Comment: @letsbondiway I added xss prevention to the code using DOMPurify html sanitizer

Answer (score 24):

If you have control over where the string containing html is coming from (ie. somewhere in your app), you can benefit from the new `<Fragment>` API, doing something like:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react'

const stringsSomeWithHtml = {
  testOne: (
    <Fragment>
      Some text <strong>wrapped with strong</strong>
    </Fragment>
  ),
  testTwo: `This is just a plain string, but it'll print fine too`,
}

...

render() {
  return <div>{stringsSomeWithHtml[prop.key]}</div>
}
```

Comment: There is no string containing html in your example. It's either jsx or plain string.

Comment: Well, yeah technically you're correct @mrkvon, however as I mention, this _solution_ is only valid if said "html"/jsx is something you have control over. Not for rendering some _raw_ html provided via an API, for example.

Prior to the `Fragment` API it was always a pain for me, that required additional `span` wraps that would sometimes mess with flex layouts. When I stumbled upon this question looking for a possible solution I thought I'd share how _I_ got around things.

Comment: Thanks! This was the only solution that worked in my case. Also, responding to mrkvon's comment on this answer : This answer indeed contains html i.e `Some text <strong>wrapped with strong</strong>` contains html tag `strong`.

Comment: @BinitaBharati But that's not a string though. If you get a string from an API like "<p>This is a String</p>"(or simply store a string in a variable), when you put this string in <Fragment>, the output will still contain the <p> tag.

Comment: Yes @Muchdecal, my answer states that this only works for "local html", not something received from an external source.

Comment: @BradAdams. Nice trick though. I can see the instances where it becomes handy.

Comment: @BradAdams I tried using your workaround but it did not work. The string that I am passing is coming from my server in the same app. 

```const stringWithHtml = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    return (<Fragment>{value}</Fragment>)
  }
```
If i replace the value to be a string with HTML in it, it does work. Any idea on resolving it?

Example of my string: 
Hello, I am <i>Mike</i>. Nice to meet you

Comment: @Yuvi this solution isn't for you then unfortunately, even if the server is "in the same app". This only _works_ for strings defined within your react application (eg. in a `const`). You'll probably want to look at `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (which isn't actually dangerous if you're using it safely) or something like `react-html-parser`.

Comment: @BradAdams thank you for the input. I will review those two options

Comment: this worked for me, I had a side component throughout my application but had different styles and content based on the page I am viewing, so put all these in the file and read those based on the page I am viewing

Answer (score 17):

You just use dangerouslySetInnerHTML method of React

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />`

Or you can implement more with this easy way: [Render the HTML raw in React app](https://www.4codev.com/react/render-the-html-raw-in-react-app-idpx6182013449177354385.html)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I used [react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html)

First install the package by `npm i --save react-render-html`

then,

```
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

renderHTML("<a class='github' href='https://github.com'><b>GitHub</b></a>")
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I do not suggest using react-render-html anymore. Its package health score is very low due to snyk: https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/react-render-html 
Html-react-parser is much better: https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/html-react-parser

Answer (score 3):

Use the react built-in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with a good HTML sanitizer like [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html).

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: sanitizeHtml(dirtyHTMLString)
}}></div>
```

All the HTML parsers I tried would strip some HTML that I didn't intend, and it's not worth the time to dig through the documentation to figure out how to stop that.

By using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like this, you're sanitizing the HTML so it isn't as dangerous.

Comment: Its working but one issue its not rendering with space

Answer (score 2):

I could not get `npm build` to work with `react-html-parser`. However, in my case, I was able to successfully make use of https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html. I had a requirement to show few html unicode characters , but they should not be directly embedded in the JSX. Within the JSX, it had to be picked from the Component's state. Component code snippet is given below :

```
constructor() 
{
this.state = {
      rankMap : {"5" : <Fragment>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</Fragment> , 
                 "4" : <Fragment>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</Fragment>, 
                 "3" : <Fragment>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734;</Fragment> , 
                 "2" : <Fragment>&#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734;</Fragment>, 
                 "1" : <Fragment>&#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734;</Fragment>}
                };
}

render() 
{
       return (<div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">{ this.state.rankMap["5"] }</small>
               </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this solution from some other answer on Stackoverflow (can't remember which one):

```
function getStringWithElements()
{
    let str=[];
    str.push(<div>This <b>truly</b> works. Thanks to {name}!</div>);
    return str;
};
```

Now inside React render:

```
return {getStringWithElements()}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react

```
const HtmlToReactParser = require('html-to-react').Parser;
let htmlInput = html.template;
let htmlToReactParser = new HtmlToReactParser();
let reactElement = htmlToReactParser.parse(htmlInput); 
return(<div>{reactElement}</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use parseReactHTMLComponent from **Jumper Package**. Just look at it, it's easy and you don't need to use JSX syntax.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jumper-module-react-simple-parser-3b8c9?file=/src/App.js .

More on Jumper:

https://github.com/Grano22/jumper/blob/master/components.js

NPM Package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jumper_react

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // For typescript

import parse, { HTMLReactParserOptions } from "html-react-parser";
import { Element } from "domhandler/lib/node";

export function contentHandler(postContent: string) {
  const options: HTMLReactParserOptions = {
    replace: (domNode: Element) => {
      if (domNode.attribs) {
        if (domNode.attribs.id === 'shortcode') {
          return <div className="leadform">Shortcode</div>;
        }
      }
    },
  };

  return parse(postContent, options);
}

// Usage: contentHandler("<span>Hello World!</span>")
```

Answer (score -5):

If you have control to the {this.props.match.description} and if you are using JSX. I would recommend not to use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML".

```
// In JSX, you can define a html object rather than a string to contain raw HTML
let description = <h1>Hi there!</h1>;

// Here is how you print
return (
    {description}
);
```