# How to display HTML from an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I have a problem with my app. I have an array:

```
players: [
    { number: 1, name: "Ben Blocker", position: "G" },
    { number: 2, name: "Dave Defender", position: "D" },
    { number: 3, name: "Sam Sweeper", position: "D" },
    { number: 4, name: "Matt Midfielder", position: "M" },
    { number: 5, name: "William Winger", position: "M" },
    { number: 6, name: "Fillipe Forward", position: "F" },
    { number: 7, name: "Bobby Ristov", position: "<h1>Test</h1>" }
  ],
```

And I would like to display the the `H1` as HTML instead of text. I have tried it like this `&lt;h1&gt;Hi there!&lt;/h1&gt;` but that does not work either. Am I missing something here? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Check this, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should an element, not string:

```
position: <h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: You can't set that as a value in an object field, it's not valid `js`

Comment: @G4bri3l Did you read the JSX documentation ? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: @Ha Ja Thank you for your answer. But now I get this: 'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Comment: Yes, you have to import the React module in your file before using jsx.