# html string to DOM element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using a text editor that generates string-like HTML and passes it to my React component.

I want to convert it to an actual DOM element when the render method of my class receives a string that is like html.

Method looks like:

```
    render() {
        var specs = this.props.specs
        var content = specs.label

        if (content[0] == '<') {
            let element = document.createElement('div')
            element.innerHTML = content
            console.log('element', element) // actual html
            console.log('element type:', typeof element) // "object"

            return element // won't work
            return <div> { element } </div> // won't work
            return <div> { [element] } <div> // won't work
        }

        return <div> { content } </div>

    }
```

Comment: use the React `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property on your `<div>` JSX.

Comment: watch this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component

Comment: That was it! Thank you. It will only be used by dev team, so XSS attacks are not an issue here. Is there another solution if I where to care about XSS though?

Comment: https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify