# React plain text to html code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I get a list of objects from the API. One of the values of each object is a plain string:

```
snippet: "Chainsmokers were re-formed as an EDM DJ duo in 2012 under the management of <span class="searchmatch">Adam</span> Alpert in New York City. Pall, who had grown up DJing, was introduced to"
```

I'd like to convert this plain string to be interpreted as html. How do I do that?

Edit:
What I try to do is map over a list in React like so:

```
const list = props.responseData.map(item => (
<li key={item.pageid}>
  {item.title}
  <br />
  {item.snippet}
</li>
));
```

The snippet one is displayed as a plain string, not as HTML code. Writing item.snippet.innerHTML doesn't work. It displays an empty list.

Comment: What technology are you using in frontend?

Comment: @Hassan Imam's question is a good one. What you have is already valid HTML.

Comment: React. It just displays the response with tags as plain text. I want to be able to display <span> etc as html code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to put it inside a div with a special attribute:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.snippet }} />
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE**

```js
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      snippet: `Chainsmokers were re-formed as an EDM DJ duo in 2012 under the management of <span class="searchmatch">Adam</span> Alpert in New York City. Pall, who had grown up DJing, was introduced to`
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.snippet }} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `obj.snippet` in a div with a specified `id`, this would be as simple as

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = obj.snippet;
```