# How to convert special characters from ASCII code to string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-entities

This is the string that appears.

```
"We&rsquo;ve got some crazy news for you guys, something that&rsquo;s 
got a positive as well as negative outlook for us Delhiites."
```

I want that the special characters get displayed instead of these codes.
This is how I am displaying the description. It is a complete string.

```
<span>{this.props.feedData.description}</span>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? (I am using ReactJS)

Comment: The data is coming from backend and I get access to it via 'this.props.description' variable. Now when I render this, It renders like this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component

Comment: Why do you comment your own question? Just **edit** it!