# Convert string to link - javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a json response

```
Indicator:true
content:"<a href=somelink target="_blank">Click here to open your message</a>"
```

I need to convert the value of `content` to link. Right now it is in string. how to make it `a href` the actual link

Unfortunately the below code isn't working

```
let content = res.content
var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML= '<div>'+content+'</div>';
var div2 = wrapper.firstChild;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: tried `wrapper.innerHTML= content;` ? and use that wrapper directly ?

Comment: Please show all relevant code and proper data structure. What is shown has mismatched quotes and is not runnable. See [mcve]

Comment: Duplicate of [**Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to directly render HTML code in React.

```
createMarkup(content) {
  return {__html: content};
}

convertFn(content) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(content)} />;
}

getLink(){
   ... get json response ...
   let content = res.content;
   let linkContent = this.convertFn(content);
}
```

Edit: This is a React.js specific example.

Comment: @raksheetbhat Where are you passing the content inside `createMarkup()`?

Comment: The OP is not using React, so I think this is not relevant

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the quotation symbols. your string ends at target.
You should put the `somelink` and the `_blank` inside quotation marks different from what you put the entire content in
ex:

```
content='<a href="somelink" target="_blank"></a>'
```

or

```
content="<a href='somelink' target='_blank'></a>"
```

**EDIT:** 
some people have misunderstood me as to saying its because he didn't put quotes outside of *somelink*. 
its not that.
**look at target**. why is `_blank` black while the rest of content is reddish?
**It's the type of quotes used that matter here.**

Comment: No, Thats not the point.. the link quotation has nothing to do.

Comment: it does, after all the string actually ends at target and resumes after blank so the part in between is treated as not string and that causes the problems

Comment: the string is long.. for that sake, i've put it short

Comment: so how does the quototion marks affect the length? were u thinking I was talking about you putting somelink instead of the actual link? im not please read the answer again

Comment: `somelink` is dummy text i've put.. which has the essential link with quotes.. so this is out of context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162319/discussion-between-ashwin-k-joseph-and-matarishvan).

Comment: I understand that  its dummy and actually it will have value... but look at the target value you put. I dont think you understand what I'm saying here.. its the quote types like " or ' that matter here . ln simpler words, why isnt the _blank  reddish like the rest of the string in content?

Comment: I pulled my dv but I really think that typos are supposed to be a comment.

Comment: @Matarishvan , Joseph is right about the link.   `content:"<a href=somelink target="_blank">Click here to open your message</a>"` is not that correct,    either it is a typo here,    or it is the cause of your problem.     The Js parser is taking only `"<a href=somelink target="` and ignoring `_blank...etc`

Comment: The thing is , the whole link i'm getting it as a value of json.. So how do you take control over that part?

Comment: In theory, when parsing the JSON, escape the inner quotes.

Answer (score 1):

use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` prop to convert any html stored inside string into actual html markup.

for e.g.

```
htmlToText(content) {
  return {__html: content};
}

render() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnertml={this.htmlToText(yourHtmlString)} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

or can be escaped

```
content = "<a href=\"somelink\" target=\"_blank\">Click here to open your message</a>"
```

please install Prettier for editor help.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

I find your code pretty working, As in the following snippet.

```js
let content = '<a href=somelink target="_blank">Click here to open your message</a>';
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = '<div>' + content + '</div>'; //No need to put in div
let div2 = wrapper.firstChild;
let a = div2.firstChild;
console.log(a.innerText)
console.log(a.getAttribute('href'), a.getAttribute('target'));
```