# How to convert html string to text?

Tags: reactjs, editor

I have this content

```
 content: "<h2 style="text-align:center;"><strong>Medicines</strong></h2>↵<p><span style="font-size: 16px;">This is regarding the medicines</span></p>"
```

I want to display it in the html form.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 0):

You must use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />`