# Using html in variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have some html in variable

```
export const PropertyDesign = {
 clubhouse: `<i class="fas fa-utensils icon-property"></i>`,
 gymnasium: `<i class="fas fa-dumbbell icon-property"></i>`,
 swimingPool: `<i class="fas fa-swimming-pool icon-property"></i>`,
 joggingTrack: `<i class="fas fa-running icon-property"></i>`, 
 playArea: `<i class="fab fa-playstation icon-property"></i>`
}
```

Which I want to use in JSX of my javascript, I initially tried this

```
    <p> {PropertyDesign[feature]} </p>
```

Where feature is my key.

but this is displaying like this in my page. Any idea how I can display icon instead of markup?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Comment: (Not the accepted answer, but the most voted one, to be precise)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the template string represetation from the object:

```
export const PropertyDesign = {
 clubhouse: <i className="fas fa-utensils icon-property"></i>,
}
```

Using template strings would just render it as string and not JSX.

Also, use `className` in JSX

Comment: I think you can't use JSX without importing react?