# How to evaluate string which contains Jsx Native code as code in Render()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parsing, eval, jsx

I have some variables stored in state which contains code to render in React Native, like:

```
JsxToRender = "<View> <Text h1 style={styles.h1}>Titre 1</Text> 
<Image source={{ uri:file:///data/data/com.app/avatar.jpg }}
style={styles.Image} /> </View>"
```

I need to return them in render() like this:

```
render() {
return (this.state.JsxToRender) }
```

How can I parse this strings into code? I tried with `eval()` in vain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Comment: thanks, but in my case it's not Html but it's already jsx.

Answer (score -2):

Kindly change this line

```
JsxToRender = "<View> <Text h1 style={styles.h1}>Titre 1</Text>
```

to

```
JsxToRender = "<View> <Text h1 style={styles.h1}>{Titre} 1</Text>
```

and use it now.

Comment: Thanks but it's not the problem, all the variable "jsxToRender" is a string. An other exemple, I have the variable test = " <View><Text>Hi, I'm valentin</Text></View>"  wich is a string fetch from an API. I just want to return this in render. The probleme is the type of variable is String.