# Convert String to HTML on React , rich text editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I am using React-Quill to add Rich text editor to my app.

have the next string store in my DB:

```
const text = '<p>Hello<strong> World</strong></p><p><strong>Next Line</strong></p>';
```

Now I want to "Render" the text const in a REACT component, but with the "Styuling" that HTML gives to it.

Hello **World**

**Next Line**

How can I do it? or other rich text editor to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component/55884366).
Also, check [this](https://medium.com/@uigalaxy7/how-to-render-html-in-react-7f3c73f5cafc)

Answer (score 6):

You can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
const text = '<p>Hello<strong> World</strong></p><p><strong>Next Line</strong></p>';

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:text}} />
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. @Akash Gupta for your nice solution. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`react-quill` supports HTML strings out of the box, so there's nothing to do except set the `value` property of the component with the string you receive from the database.

```
<ReactQuill value={text} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah `react-quill` is the way for working with React. I also have had a small demo to demonstrate how it works (we might have to put some css files to make it looking good): https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-hill-mdxji?file=/src/App.js