# Pass Component from JS Object as props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading from a JS object (from JSX) and trying to pass value of a component but it's rendered as string.

I tried placing components (in `icon` key of `data` see below) in `{}` but that doesn't help as `data` gives an error.

Here's the simplified version of the files.

`data.js` as below:

```
const data = [
 {
    title: "some title",
    desc: "some desc",
 },
 [
   {
     icon: "<TwitterIcon />",
     title: "title 1",
     desc: "desc 1",
   },
   {
     icon: "<FacebookIcon />",
     title: "title 2",
     desc: "desc 2",
   },
 ],
]

export { data }
```

`index.js` that reads `data` object and passes as props to `AnotherComponent`:

```
import { data } from "../path/to/data"
import AnotherComponent from "../path/to/AnotherComponent"

const Homepage = () => {

  return (
    <AnotherComponent {...data} />
  )
}
```

`AnotherComponent.jsx` as below:

```
import {TwitterIcon, FacebookIcon} from "../path/to/CustomIcons"

const AnotherComponent = ({ ...data}) => {

  return (
    {data[1].map(item => (
      <div>{item.icon}</div> // this prints string as opposed to rendering the component
      <div>{item.title}</div>
      <div>{item.desc}</div>
    ))}
  )
}
```

`index.js` returns:

```
<div><TwitterIcon /></div>
<div>title 1</div>
<div>desc 1</div>
<div><FacebookIcon /></div>
<div>title 2</div>
<div>desc 2</div>
```

Comment: JSX is not an HTML string. Wrap the data in some function called within the render cycle and render the icon directly in the object: `icon: <TwitterIcon />,`

Comment: If you do not control the data, see [how to render custom JSX strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64191372/1218980), though it depends on the use-case and just fixing the design of the app might fix the problem without a custom solution.

Comment: Nikita wasn't wrong (in their deleted answer), spreading an array on a JSX element will use all indexes as props, which are used as object keys, destructured in the component, etc, which is code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the object you are defining as:

```js
{
  icon: "<TwitterIcon />",
  title: "title 1",
  desc: "desc 1",
}
```

Don't use `"<TwitterIcon />"` It will always return a string, instead use `TwitterIcon`:

```
{
  icon: TwitterIcon,
  title: "title 1",
  desc: "desc 1",
}
```

And finally, call it where you need it, in this way:

```
const AnotherComponent = ({ ...data}) => {

  return (
    {data[1].map(item => (
      <div><item.icon /></div> // HERE: check I'm calling item.icon as React Component
      <div>{item.title}</div>
      <div>{item.desc}</div>
    ))}
  )
}
```

In this way you are passing the icon to anywhere you want and not just passing a string. So, you can call it as a Component when you need it to render. I do it a lot in my work.

Comment: Thanks Hector, this worked like a charm! You're awesome :)

Comment: @megatower I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Waw thanks. that would be so interesting if it can receive props.

Comment: @Jovylle actually it can. But you should have a property in the object like `iconProps`, this would be an object with all the properties you may need. Then when you call component do `<item.icon {...item.iconProps} />`. That should do the work ;)

Comment: Thanks @Hector gonna try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass directly the icon component in **the object**, like this:

```
const data = [
{
    title: "some title",
    desc: "some desc",
 },
 [
   {
     icon: <TwitterIcon />,
     title: "title 1",
     desc: "desc 1",
   } ...
```

Then in **index.js** you can do (it is more clear to pass down props like this):

```
const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <AnotherComponent data={data} />
  )
}
```

In **AnotherComponent.jsx** now you can do:

```
const AnotherComponent = ({data}) => {
  return (
    {data[1].map(item => (
      <div>{item.icon}</div>
      <div>{item.title}</div>
      <div>{item.desc}</div>
    ))}
  )
}
```

Comment: While this will look like it works, the `<TwitterIcon />` lifecycle might be messed up as it's not created and updated in the app, but rather outside of it. A way to make it work well is to wrap the `data` in a function which returns a new array each time the calling component is rendered.

Comment: Sounds better. You can call that function on useEffect