# How to change the part of string into JSX element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a string that have a `<a> text </a>` tag in it, but it was just read by the browser as a plain text when displayed inside a ReactJS's element,

Here is my sample code

```js
const datas = [
    {
        title: 'the title1',
        description: `the link was in <a href="#">here</a>, please click`
    },
    {
        title: 'the title2',
        description: `the link was in the last <a href="#">word</a>`
    }
]


const renderDatas = () => {
    return datas.map(data => {
        return (
            <div>
                {data.description}
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

I already tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758914/6800631) and the only difference is, I'm using a string literal (`), but it just only read by the browser as plain text either.

My expected result was to make that `<a href="#">here</a>` a clickable link when the browser reads it.

Comment: It's unclear *how* you've tried that accepted answer, given that you haven't used what that *question* did. As far as we can see you're not currently trying to set the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop of `div`. For example:

```
const renderDatas = () => {
    return datas.map(data => {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.description }} />
        )
    })
}
```

But, **note**, that, as the documentation says: *In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.*