# React - HTML element inside to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, redux

**I have an object I want to set an html element inside this object**

```
    {
        titleName: "Indorction",
        heading: 'Welcome to JavaScript',
        iconName: faDotCircle,
        description: [
            `
            Do we even need to introduce `${<p>HTML element</p>}`? It’s one of the most popular programming 
            languages on the planet!
            Ever visited a website that made you think…"Hey, this website is really cool and
            `
        ],
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to flag as duplicate but you can find your answer here:
[Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Basically you want to render a string as HTML, which is a dangerous practice so beware.

```js
const x = {
        titleName: "Indorction",
        heading: 'Welcome to JavaScript',
        iconName: faDotCircle,
        description: [
            `
            Do we even need to introduce <p>HTML element</p>? It’s one of the most popular programming 
            languages on the planet!
            Ever visited a website that made you think…"Hey, this website is really cool and
            `
        ],
    },
```

And inside your render function:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: x.description }}></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just want to add style to a specific word from the object text, for example, change the color of a word, maybe there are options?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I guess you would have to create a custom parser for it or use the above innerHtml. I think a reasonable solution would be to create a array of objects with properties, e.g.:
`description: [{text: 'Do we even', className: 'red-text'}, {text: 'need to introduce', className: ''}]`
And then map it to a list of spans, e.g.: `<span className={item.className}>{item.text}></span>`. This would give you more control over the whole process and be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript_Lessons_Objects.js**

```
{
    titleName: "Indorction",
    heading: 'Welcome to JavaScript',
    iconName: faDotCircle,
    description: [
      `
       Do we even need to introduce <b class="hal">JavaScript</b>? It’s one of the most 
       popular programming languages on the planet!.
      `
   ],
},
```

**Lesson.jsx**

```
{ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"])}
```