# How to display html code from a json data in my react js page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a  component in a react js app, which calls an api using fetch and get some json data like below. How can i display the html in the json data as is, in my own html code?

```
   data = {
              duration : "1", 
              html : "<div><p>some message here</p><p> more text here <span> styled text <span><p></div>"
          }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the `html` as raw text? Or you want to render the `html`?

Comment: i want to render html

Comment: Maybe this can work. $("body").append($(data.html)); If jquery works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should use a package  `html-react-parser`

```
npm i html-react-parser
```

then

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser'
const yourHtmlString = '<h1 >Hello</h1>' // it's mean your data state html field
```

after just call like this

```
 <div>
    {parse(yourHtmlString)}
</div>
```

Also you can find more detail about this in this question

[Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)