# remove "" from varialble of html codeblock next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i just want to remove "" so insted of `<H2>When Does Thor: Love And Thunder Realase &Nbsp;In Disney Plus?&Nbsp;</H2>` it will be displayed as `When Does Thor: Love And Thunder Realase In Disney Plus?`

i have edited my question now u understand what i am looking for

[image]

```
  {posts.map((itm, k) => {
          return (
            <>
       <div key={itm._id} className="Question-one">
                <h2> {itm.Name}</h2>
                 <div>
                  {itm.htmldata}
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="username">
                <span className="username2">--{itm.username}</span>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </>
```

Comment: Not sure, but could you try to embed the HTML text inside `pre` tags?

Comment: can u explain how to do that

Comment: "i have edited my question now u understand what i am looking for" — The duplicate still covers that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

For that way you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` props in the JSX tag.

### Answer

React just support `innerHTML` with the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. And if you just input `HTML`, react are going to parse it just `String` data type. So, you can't get what you want

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: itm.htmldata }}></div>
```

### ETC

Even you can use [`react-html-renderer`](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+html+renderer&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKR823KR823&oq=react+html+renderer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l2j0i390l4.4105j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) library

Comment: pls expailin this answer

Comment: the html code is in itm.htmldata how can i display it

Comment: That's going to inject the HTML into the DOM as elements. The question is asking how to **remove** the HTML entirely.

Comment: i just i want to remove the "" so the code is displayed propery rather than with htmltags

Comment: Yeap I think you want to parse HTML and render with clearly just string right?

Comment: stark jeon pls help me by changing the piece of code i have provied ur explantion is not making anysence to me @Quentin pls reopen this question that answer doesnot fit my answer

Comment: I think Stark's answer is correct. Not sure why it has been down voted. Try something like this - `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: itm.htmldata }}></div>`

Comment: @vivekkn — I've reread the question twice. Either it does answer it or the question needs to be edited to clarify what you want.

Comment: @StarkJeon i just want to remove "" so insted of `<H2>When Does Thor: Love And Thunder Realase &Nbsp;In Disney Plus?&Nbsp;</H2>` it will be displayed as `When Does Thor: Love And Thunder Realase In Disney Plus?`

Comment: @AnindyaDey — The question says "removes all the html tags and makes it simple senteance" — this *renders* the HTML and creates elements. It doesn't remove the tags.

Comment: And if the question is just very badly written and this is what the OP wants … then it is just a different duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component that doesn't need another answer.

Comment: I think there's lot of confusion in this question itself. The answer provided should suffice the question asked. If not, a new question with clear explanation should be opened.

Comment: @AnindyaDey ur answer is correct if u put up a answer i will give u a correct

Comment: @vivekkn good to know. Thanks, but unfortunately the question has been marked as duplicate and hence, no further answers can be added. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I think my answer is right? and I edit more with the example from @AnindyaDey