# how to access this json data in react return

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How i can able access this

```
{
    "user": {
        "questionsz": [
            {
                "_id": "62737b55583793fad608aaa2",
                "question": "<b>Directions(Q.1 to Q.5 ): </b><p>What approximate value should come in place of question mark (?) in the following questions?  ",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
        }
    }
```

Here Below my code

```
const index = (user) => {
    return (
      <div>
            question.  {user.question}
      </div>  
    )
  }
```

how can i access question property from above json to return actual data to show in frontend

Comment: Need to know more to answer this question. Where is the data stored? Is it coming from an API call, is it in a local file?

Comment: its from API when console log inside index function JSON data shows like above

Comment: https://media.todaysprint.com/i/OhTrNI56.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very much clear but if you are accepting the JSON file as a props to your functional component you could [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the json data like

```js
const index = ({ user }) => {
    return (
      <div>
            question.  {user.question}
      </div>  
    )
  }
```

Now the `user` props contains the

```json
{
  "questionsz": [
    {
      "_id": "62737b55583793fad608aaa2",
      "question": "<b>Directions(Q.1 to Q.5 ): </b><p>What approximate value should come in place of question mark (?) in the following questions?  ",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

which you can access the questions like `user.question`

But my suggestion is to show the data in list format like

```js
const index = ({ user }) => {
    return (
      <div>
            show user.question in table and question.question is html string
            <ul>
                {user.questionsz.map(question => (
                    <li key={question._id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:  question.question }} />
                ))}
            </ul>
      </div>  
    )
  }
```

i added `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` because i see the question is html strings. refer here for more info about rendering html string [Render HTML string as real HTML in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/render-html-string-as-real-html-in-a-react-component)

Comment: thanks its my bad i missed curly bracket const index = ({ user })

Answer (score 0):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute.
More info here-
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml