# ReactJS fetched html data manupilation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a mongodb database where I saved raw html in it. I have created a custom attribute in the html called kk-id to mention objects inside the html. I want to replace that particular html tag with an anchor tag.

I figured a way to do it using *vanilla javascript*, however I was wondering if there was a more efficient *reactjs* way to do it.

data example

```html
<p>Hello <span kk-id="123">John Doe</span></p>
```

where John Doe's id is *123* saved in it.

```js
/// react component
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function TestComponent() {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState(
    `<p>Hello <span kk-id="123">John Doe</span><br /></p>`
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const span = document.querySelector(`[kk-id]`);
    if (span) {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = "/people/john-doe";
      a.innerText = span.innerText;
      span.parentNode.replaceChild(a, span);
    }
  }, [html]);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) and just do

```
import parse from "html-react-parser";
...

const newParsedHtml = parse(html, {
    replace: ({attribs}) => {
        if (domNode.attribs && domNode.attribs.id === "123") {
            return <span>dynamic text here</span>
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This solotion is ALMOST correct.
`const options = {
    replace: (domNode) => {
      if (domNode.attribs?.kkid) {
        return <Link to="/people/john-doe">{domNode.children[0].data}</Link>;
      }
    },
  };`

Answer (score 0):

I hope vanilla js is the simplest way to do it. For enhancement purpose you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758631/11368366). it will be more readable and reusable.