# How to render HTML tags embedded in JS array values

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props, array.prototype.map

When calling data from an array from an API, some of the array values have HTML tags (`title` and `display_name` below):

```
    {
        "id": "https://openalex.org/W2101293576",
        "doi": "https://doi.org/10.1128/aem.02073-07",
        "title": "Differential Roles of Poly- <i>N</i> -Acetylglucosamine Surface Polysaccharide and Extracellular DNA in <i>Staphylococcus aureus</i> and <i>Staphylococcus epidermidis</i> Biofilms",
        "display_name": "Differential Roles of Poly- <i>N</i> -Acetylglucosamine Surface Polysaccharide and Extracellular DNA in <i>Staphylococcus aureus</i> and <i>Staphylococcus epidermidis</i> Biofilms"
    }
```

When I pass it into a React component,
`<h1>{props.paper.title}</h1>`
it obviously renders an `h1` element which literally reads

> "Differential Roles of Poly- <i>N</i> -Acetylglucosamine Surface
> Polysaccharide and Extracellular DNA in <i>Staphylococcus
> aureus</i>"

Is there a way I can incorporate those HTML tags into the rendering or parse them out of the code if I can't apply them to the actual text?

Comment: yes search for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render HTML string as real HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/how-to-render-html-string-as-real-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) or can use [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) package.