# HTML text in span - Tags not getting implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I have span -

```
<span> {textToRender} </span>
```

I am rendering html text (as string) with span.

```
some text <br/> some text <br/> some text <ol>text
```

This is getting rendered as text only in javascript. Html tags are not getting applied over it.

```
<span> {textToRender} </span>
```

Comment: I’d start by searching for “react render html string”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render HTML string as real HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758136/how-to-render-html-string-as-real-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it following way:

```
 <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:textToRender}}></span>
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

same as the guys suggest you can use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML,
Although the name suggests danger in **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** and its use, taking the necessary measure by using a well-developed sanitizer ensures the code to be clean and does not run unexpected scripts when rendered within the React node.
you can use DOMPurify for exemple

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'

const App = () => {
  const data = `lorem <b onmouseover="alert('mouseover');">ipsum</b>`
  const sanitizedData = () => ({
    __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(data)
  })

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={sanitizedData()}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nice. Using `DOMPurify` is much better than simply setting HTML dangerously.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, as `React.js` automatically escapes the extrapolations to prevent injection attacks and other vulnerabilities. In case you want HTML to get parsed, and proper tags be applied, you can use JSX instead of `String` or set HTML explicitly as follows:

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: textToRender }} />
```

Or
convert your `textToRender` to JSX.

```
textToRender = <>some text <br/> some text <br/> some text</>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{_html:textToRender}}/>
```

Comment: Explain in your answer why this solves the problem?